# Word Automation Service Documentation

Tags: 2013, development, word-automation

I am currently prototyping a custom ribbon button to merge several office files into a single PDF.

I plan to use the Word Automation Service to facilitate this however while looking at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee559408) it appears to refer to SP2010, we have SP2013 in our environment. I haven't been able to locate any documents regarding this service in SP2013.

Is this documentation still relevant for 2013 or is my Google Fu lacking today?

Answer (score 1):

There is one notable addition to WAS on SharePoint 2013, which is the instant conversions versus the timer job-based conversions. More information can be found at http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/15731.sharepoint-2013-new-features-in-word-automation-services.aspx.